# Python list comparison: Can this code run faster?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

The idea is to apply some function on each element in each list, then compare two lists by the value returned by the function.

My current solution works but is not fast enough. running "python -m cProfile" gives sth. like:

```
  ncalls    tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  2412505   13.335   0.000    23.633   0.000   common.py:38(<genexpr>)
  285000    5.434    0.000    29.067   0.000   common.py:37(to_dict)
  142500    3.392    0.000    35.948   0.000   common.py:3(compare_lists)
```

Here is my code, I would like to know how to optimize it to run faster.

```
import itertools

def compare_lists(li1, li2, value_func1=None, value_func2=None):
    """ Compare *li1* and *li2*, return the results as a list in the following form:

    [[data seen in both lists], [data only seen in li1], [data only seen in li2]]

    and [data seen in both lists] contains 2 tuple: [(actual items in li1), (actual items in li2)]

    * *value_func1* callback function to li1, applied to each item in the list, returning the **logical** value for comparison
    * *value_func2* callback function to li2, similarly

    If not supplied, lists will be compared as it is.

    Usage::

        >>> compare_lists([1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 5])
        >>> ([(1, 3), (1, 3)], [2], [5])

    Or with callback functions specified::

        >>> f = lambda x: x['v']
        >>>
        >>> li1 = [{'v': 1}, {'v': 2}, {'v': 3}]
        >>> li2 = [1, 3, 5]
        >>>
        >>> compare_lists(li1, li2, value_func1=f)
        >>> ([({'v': 1}, {'v': 3}), (1, 3)], [{'v': 2}], [5])

    """

    if not value_func1:
        value_func1 = (lambda x:x)
    if not value_func2:
        value_func2 = (lambda x:x)

    def to_dict(li, vfunc):
        return dict((k, list(g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(li, vfunc))

    def flatten(li):
        return reduce(list.__add__, li) if li else []

    d1 = to_dict(li1, value_func1)
    d2 = to_dict(li2, value_func2)

    if d1 == d2:
        return (li1, li2), [], []

    k1 = set(d1.keys())
    k2 = set(d2.keys())

    elems_left  = flatten([d1[k] for k in k1 - k2])
    elems_right = flatten([d2[k] for k in k2 - k1])

    common_keys = k1 & k2
    elems_both  = flatten([d1[k] for k in common_keys]), flatten([d2[k] for k in common_keys])

    return elems_both, elems_left, elems_right
```

Edit:

zeekay suggests using set, which is also what I was doing, except that I make a dict for each list first, then compare the keys using set, finally return the original elements using the dict. I realized that the speed actually depends on which one will take more time -- the callback function, or the groupby. In my case, the possible callback functions are mostly dot access on objects, and the length of lists can be large causing groupby on lists takes more time.

In the improved version each callback function is executed more than once on every single element, which I considered is a waste and has been trying to avoid in the first place, but it's still much faster than my original approach, and much simpler.

```
def compare_lists(li1, li2, vf1=None, vf2=None):
    l1 = map(vf1, li1) if vf1 else li1
    l2 = map(vf2, li2) if vf2 else li2

    s1, s2 = set(l1), set(l2)
    both, left, right = s1 & s2, s1 - s2, s2 - s1

    orig_both = list((x for x in li1 if vf1(x) in both) if vf1 else both), list((x for x in li2 if vf2(x) in both) if vf2 else both)
    orig_left = list((x for x in li1 if vf1(x) in left) if vf1 else left)
    orig_right = list((x for x in li2 if vf2(x) in right) if vf2 else right)

    return orig_both, orig_left, orig_right
```

Comment: there are smarter ways to flatten a list, using `sum`, for other comparison approaches see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches

Comment: @Fredrik Thanks. sum does not work for list of lists though... sum([1, 2], [3]) raises TypeError.

Comment: @Shaung it does if you use it like `sum([[],[1],[2,3]], [])`, note the 2nd argument `[]`.

Comment: he would be referring to `sum([[1, 2], [3]], [])`

Comment: @Dan D... snap!

Comment: Oh I see now. Cool! Wish I knew that earlier

Answer (score 3):

So it seems you primarily want to use your callback functions to pull the value to compare out of an object, if you don't mind simplifying how compared items are returned, a faster and simpler approach would be:

```
def simple_compare(li1, li2, value_func1=None, value_func2=None):
        s1, s2 = set(map(value_func1, li1)), set(map(value_func2, li2))
        common = s1.intersection(s2)
        s1_diff, s2_diff = s1.difference(s2), s2.difference(s1)
        return common, s1_diff, s2_diff

>>> simple_compare(li1, li2, value_func1=f)
<<< (set([1, 3]), set([2]), set([5]))

>>> compare_lists(li1, li2, value_func1=f)
<<< (([{'v': 1}, {'v': 3}], [1, 3]), [{'v': 2}], [5])
```

Which depending on actual use case, might be something you could live with. It's definitely a lot faster:

```
>>> timeit x = simple_compare(xrange(10000), xrange(10000))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.3 ms per loop

>>> timeit x = compare_lists(xrange(10000), xrange(10000))
10 loops, best of 3: 53.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: You did not read my question, dude :) What I am trying to do is compare lists by the value after applied to some function, and return the original elements.

Comment: You can of course use my answer to modify your original function and support applying functions to values. As is, it merely demonstrates how much faster using the `set` methods would be.

Comment: yes, quite simply by for example using `s1, s2 = set(map(func1, l1)), set(map(func2, l2))`

Comment: Yeah I suppose I'll update with an alternate approach using `map`, actually. Format of return is a bit different, but I think this makes more sense honestly. Might not work for you, but if you can make it work it'd be a lot simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really trying to do sets, rather than using a list as a bag look at this code

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]

print list (set(a) - set(b))
print list (set(b) - set(a))
print list (set(a) & set(b))
print list (set(a) | set(b))
print list (set(a) ^ set(b))
```

=========

Output

```
[1]
[4]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If counts matter, then you need to use the Counter class from collections

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,1,2,3,3]
b = [1,3,4,4]

print "a      ",a
print "b      ",b 
print "union  ", list ((Counter(a) | Counter(b)).elements())
print "a not b", list ((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).elements())
print "b not a", list ((Counter(b) - Counter(a)).elements())
print "b and a", list ((Counter(b) & Counter(a)).elements())
```

which gives this answer

```
a       [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
b       [1, 3, 4, 4]
union   [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
a not b [1, 2, 3]
b not a [4, 4]
b and a [1, 3]
```

Always better to use the inbuilt, rather than write your own